# Using timer with Quartz and Apache Camel

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I've a problem with Camel and quartz.
I wanto to execute a trigger with Quartz so i wrote this simple code, where I want to print the time every two second on the console :

```
 public class TestQuartz {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                from("quartz://myTimer?trigger.repeatInterval=2000&trigger.repeatCount=-1").setBody().simple("Current time is ${header.firedTime}").to("stream:out");
            }
        });

        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        context.stop();
    }
}
```

And I obtain this exception: `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[quartz://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=0+0+8+... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: quartz://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=0+0+8+*+*+* due to: No component found with scheme: quartz`

I start by saying that I've inserted in the pom.xml the dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quartz2</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

where camel.version is 2.15.1

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're importing the camel-quartz**2** component in your pom.xml file whilst trying to use the old quartz component.

Quartz: http://camel.apache.org/quartz.html

Quartz2: http://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html

Try the following URI for the route:

```
quartz2://myTimer?trigger.repeatInterval=2000&trigger.repeatCount=-1
```

Comment: I tried it, now I obtain an exception with the same type but  the cause is "No component found with scheme: stream" whereas before was "No component found with scheme: quartz".

Comment: You are using the stream component as an endpoint, have you imported it in you're pom.xml as well? 
Add the maven dependency found here: http://camel.apache.org/stream.html

Comment: It runs but now it doesn't print the time. It prints only "Current time is".

Comment: Did you use the camelinaction example and replaced the timer with the quartz component? Anyway, it looks like your interval definition and header field are based on a timer component and not on quartz. Read the following doc: http://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html for correct URIs and message headers fields